# ¿Cómo conectarme a internet vía cable en UBUNTU MATE?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Tengo UBUNTU MATE y no me puedo conectar al wifi, creo que es porque me faltan instalar unos controladores, el tema es que no puedo instalarlos sin internet, asi que pense en conectarme via cable pero resulta que tampoco me detecta , asi que adjunto algunas fotos de mi configuracion de red para ver si por favor me puede ayudar, quiza falta agregar algo a mi config:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo hacer la pregunta en https://askubuntu.com/, muy posiblemente quede cerrada aquí.

Comment: pero esta todo en ingles :(

Comment: @natan, ya tratamos de conectar vía wifi (en el chat al que se derivó la conversación no volviste a entrar) y ahora el problema persiste con el cable. ¿Has comprobado que puedas salir a internet con otras máquinas a través de tu router?

Comment: Si, otras maquinas funcionan perfectamente. INcluso cuando esta maquina tenia windows se podia conectar tan solo con poner el cable.

Comment: pasate al chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96170/discussion-on-question-by-natan-como-hacer-que-ubuntu-reconozca-mi-red-wifi

Comment: al instalar asegurate de instalar con soporte a controladores de terceros.

Comment: no puedo marcar controladores de terceros porque no tengo acceso a internet ni siquiera con cable

Comment: eso debiste hacerlo al momento de instalar con eso te aseguras que se instaler más drivers y tu hardware trabaje mejor

Comment: lo marque pero no tenia conxion a internet

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  no parece consistente con la temática del sitio